# How to define a custom escape sequence for a string, and then parse it?

Tags: ruby, regex, escaping, character, special-characters

I'm writing a simple Ruby on Rails app. I have a model with a "description" attribute, which is a string.

I'd like to display this string in a view, but have *some* of the words in the string rendered using a special music font (one of the ones located [here](http://tagg.org/zmisc/fonts.html)), and the rest to use the main font of the website. Problem is, since the description attribute is just a string that is persisted to the database, there's no real way to tell which words should use the special font...

The only way I can think of would be to define my own "escape sequence" or "special characters" that would allow me to indicate to the view whether a word should use the special font.

For example, say I have the following string:

```
cat dog rabbit elephant
```

If I wanted "dog" and "elephant" to use the special font, I could the store the string in the database as:

```
cat ${dog} rabbit ${elephant}
```

In other words, use "${}" as the custom escape sequence.

And then in my view I would have a helper method to process the string, and generate the appropriate HTML/CSS for words that use the escape sequence. For example, this is the kind of output I would expect it to produce:

```
<p>cat <span class="music">dog</span> rabbit <span class="music">elephant</span></p>
```

Does this seem like a reasonable solution? If so, how would I implement the view method to parse the string and the escape characters? I'm guessing some sort of regular expression?

*In a way, it's sort of similar to how LaTeX allows you to render mathematical equations. For instance, in LaTeX, to activate the mathematical font for particular characters, you can do:*

```
 \mathnormal{some text}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just store the html snippet directly in your database.

```
<p>cat <span class="music">dog</span> rabbit <span class="music">elephant</span></p>
```

Otherwise, you would have to remake the HTML string every time it was requested.

If that's not an option, you could use a simple regex to replace the `${}` with an html snippet.

```
string = "cat ${dog} rabbit ${elephant}"
string.gsub /\$\{([^\}]+)\}/, '<span class="music">\1</span>'

    => "cat <span class=\"music\">dog</span> rabbit <span class=\"music\">elephant</span>"
```

Comment: Thanks!

I'd prefer to not store HTML in the database, so that second solution using `gsub` works really well.